# jquery hide/show Div works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a page that is very long with a lot of query and ajax in it.  This is the shortened version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<style>
    #holder{position:relative;}
    #waiting{width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:200; padding-top:20%; text-align:center; background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}
    #waiting img {width:200px;}

</style>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function showStep3(){
            $('#waiting').show();
            // this is where a ton of jquery including ajax goes
            runQuery();
            $('#waiting').hide();
        }

        $(function(){

            $('#waiting').hide();

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="holder">
    <div id="waiting"><img src="img/waiting.gif"></div>
        <div id="criteria">
            whole bunch of HTML
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the area marked "this is where a ton of jquery including ajax goes" there are some ajax calls that are set to  async:false (in case that makes a difference).

Basically I hide the "waiting" div on load then when I start function showStep3 I show it, do a bunch stuff and then hide it when all is done.

This works as expected in Firefox but not in chrome or IE9.  Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  And why not initialize the CSS so that it's hidden to start, then only *show it when needed*?

Comment: The initial hide works but the show in the beginning of the "showStep3" functions doesn't work.  its almost as if the function blows right past it ans there is no error and everything else in the functions (not show) works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the initial hide works?  Is it possible that your CSS doesn't render in IE and Chrome, and therefor you *think* it's been hidden when in fact it was never visible in the first place?  Try commenting out your initial hide() call (on page load) and see what you see.

Comment: Why not put $('#waiting').hide(); as a success callback in ajax?

Comment: Yes, the initial hide works.  If I comment it out works correctly in all browsers. The initial show does NOT work however.